# Help using SFHFKeychainUtils

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, keychain

I'm trying to use SHFHKeychainUtils in my project, but I keep getting the following error when I build:

> ".objc_class_name_SFHFKeychainUtils", referenced from:
>   literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@SFHFKeychainUtils in ResultsViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I added Security.framework via Target > Get Info > General

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you haven't added the files SFHFKeychainUtils (.h and .m) to your project, or that they aren't included for your target (check this by making sure the check-box at the right of the line for this file is checked).

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much indeed. The files weren't included for my target.